# Update my PayPal card via 3rd party app?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to update my card details stored in my PayPal account via a 3rd party app with the use of an API? I came across the below documentation but wasn't too sure in which scenarios it could be used?

"Update a stored credit card
Operation

PATCH /v1/vault/credit-cards/

Use this call to modify a credit card."

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API's available for updating the credit card on your PayPal account.
But, using Adaptive Payments, you can just add a new Payment Card using `AddPaymentCard` [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/AddPaymentCard_API_Operation/).
Although, you would need to apply for an application `at apps.paypal.com`

The [vault](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/) is for REST API which is used to store(encrypt) the buyer's credit card information and could be used for future transactions.The Vault API provides a secure way to store customer credit cards. By storing cards with PayPal, you can avoid storing them on your servers.